# Inline Button layout breaks dropdown content layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have 3 dropdown buttons inline with each other. I use `btn-group`, but this breaks the layout of one of the dropdowns. The layout of the dropdown content needs to be wide, but using `btn-group` or `display:inline-block` forces it to be the standard, narrow dropdown which breaks the layout of my content.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64sjkunq/)

Note how the first dropdown is wide. If you change the parent div to `btn-group` or `display:inline-block`, the content shrinks and becomes narrow. I need to keep the wide dropdown, and at the same time make all the buttons appear on one row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to play around with the functionality some so they big box isn't showing the same time as the narrow ones, but your problem is that by setting the `.dropdown` class to `position:relative` you're limiting the width of it's child elements. By removing this and changing the top position of your children, it should look the way you want it to.

```
.dropup, .dropdown {
  position: inherit;
}
.dropdown-menu {
   top:40px;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/benneb10/64sjkunq/1/)

Comment: I noticed that if you have content above the buttons the top: position will work from that div. Is there a way to get the dropdown position right besides playing around with the top position? If the screen size changes the top: position will also be off. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qn4cgsfa/

Answer (score 1):

You may try with the following html

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100%;">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some large content hereSome large content hereSome large content hereSome large content hereSome large content here
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100%;">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100%;">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```